# NHibernate - "No row with the given identifier exists" but it is there

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am using NHibernate and this error appears when I use Get method of Session.

This is my code:

```
public T GetById(object id)
    {
        T entity;
        entity = (T)ReportHttpModule.CurrentSession.Get(typeof(T), id);
        return entity;
    }
```

note that I don't get this error when use `CreateCriteria(T)` before calling that method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. It is weird but it was a problem in mapping file. One of my columns had `not-null="true"` in mapping file but in database was not nullable!

Comment: Isn't `not-null="true"` the same thing as `not nullable`?