# C# Linq group by multiple column getting No row with the given identifier exists

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Earlier I raised an issue about how to group by using linq in c#. Below is the link.
Now I am getting an error when one of my group by key is null. 
basically I

```
var result = collection.GroupBy(item => new { item.PNO, item.GCode })
          .Select(grouping => new 
          {
              PNO = grouping.Key.PNO,
              GCode = grouping.Key.GCode,//when this GCode is null, getting error
              Options = grouping.Select(item => new { Color = item.Color, Size = item.Size, Amount = item.Amount }).ToList()
          }).ToList();
```

Error I am getting is something like:

```
No row with the given identifier exists[....]
```

Can anyone please suggest me a solution for this?

[C# Linq how to use group by to get the desired output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893594/c-sharp-linq-how-to-use-group-by-to-get-the-desired-output/38895026#38895026)

Thanks

Comment: when I run that code on some sample data eith `GCode` null it works. Please show what is the data you have.

Comment: basically I am getting the data from an NHibernate query result.

Answer (score 0):

When searching for the error I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557526/nhibernate-no-row-with-the-given-identifier-exists-but-it-is-there) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695931/nhibernate-no-row-with-the-given-identifier-exists).

Another possible solution is to use `??`

```
var result = collection.GroupBy(item => new { item.PNO ?? string.Empty, item.GCode ?? string.Empty})
          .Select(grouping => new 
          {
              PNO = grouping.Key.PNO,
              GCode = grouping.Key.GCode,//when this GCode is null, getting error
              Options = grouping.Select(item => new { Color = item.Color, Size = item.Size, Amount = item.Amount }).ToList()
          }).ToList();
```